# Three Envelopes Problem

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Monty Hall problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96826/the-monty-hall-problem)

Three envelopes are presented in front of you by an interviewer. One contains a job offer, the other two contain rejection letters. You pick one of the envelopes. The interviewer then shows you the contents of one of the other envelopes, which is a rejection letter. The interviewer now gives you the opportunity to switch envelope choices. Should you switch?

Comment: @Marvis Sounds about right.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that, I will vote to close the question.

Comment: It depends .. does the interviewer know which envelope contains what? Does the interviewer always open an envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yea u should

P of correct envelope the first time you picked is 1/3

That 1/3 has not changed so by switching you essentially make a switch with a P of 1/2.

Or something along those lines.