# Monty-Hall-Problem / Complete Tree of Possibilities

Tags: probability, monty-hall, decision-trees

**EDIT:** I know that this is a trigger topic. I know there is a hell of posts out there. I don't need to be told, that I should switch, neither why. I want to know, what is wrong with those trees. If there is a post out there explaining it, I would happy accept that. But an answer like *"The trees must be wrong because different calculation shows that odds are 1/3 and 2/3"* does not answer why the trees are wrong.

Another question on Monty-Hall-Problem:

I totally understand all reasoning behind the classic problem and it pitfalls when it is not completely defined. I am also familiar with the Bayes' Theorem. I wanted to do a round up on the topic for a blog post and while I was tinkering with illustration I stumbled upon a thing I can solve:

I tried to illustrate the problem with a complete tree of possibilities. Without loss of generality I can assume that the car is behind door three and I have three start cases, where the player can choose door one, two or three:

`Case 1       Case 2       Case 3 
[G][G][C]    [G][G][C]    [G][G][C]
 ^               ^               ^`

Case 1 expands to only one possible branch, Monty has to open door two. After that the player can **stay** or **switch**. Case 2 is similar:

`Case 1
[G][G][C] -> [G][X][C] -> [G][X][C] Stay: Goat
 ^            ^        |   ^
                       -> [G][X][C] Switch: Car
                                 ^
Case 2
[G][G][C] -> [X][G][C] -> [X][G][C] Stay: Goat
    ^            ^     |      ^
                       -> [X][G][C] Switch: Car
                                 ^`

Case 3 is the tricky one. Since the player picked the right door, Monty has two possible alternatives, the case is branching into two, then into four:

`Case 3
[G][G][C] -> [X][G][C] -> [X][G][C] Stay: Car
       ^  |         ^  |         ^
          |            -> [X][G][C] Switch: Goat
          |                   ^
          -> [G][X][C] -> [G][X][C] Stay: Car
                    ^  |         ^
                       -> [G][X][C] Switch: Goat
                           ^`

And here's my dilemma. I got 2 goats and 2 cars while **staying** and also 2 goats and 2 cars while **switching**. My first reasoning was to say, the both sub-trees in case 3 are equivalent, therefore I would have 2 goats and 1 car with **Stay** and 1 goat and 2 cars with **Switch**, as expected. But then case 1 and case 2 should also be equivalent and I would be down to 1 and 1.

I found another clue: I give Monty the possibility to choose. If I define the problem as: *Monty must open the goat-door with the lowest number*, everything would be fine again. **But:** How can the choice of the door by Monty affect the state-probability of being on a car-door?

Again: I know, this can't be right. I know, how to calculate all the stuff, but I can't figure out, what is wrong with making this tree and counting good events vs possible events.

Comment: This topic has been beaten to death at this and various other sites. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010434/monty-hall-problem) for example

Comment: When Monty is allowed to choose, the assumption in the classic set up is that both goats are equally likely to be chosen - i.e. with probability 1/2. So the odds of staying to switching will be 1:2. If Monty always choose the lowest door, then you can use Bayes theorem to calculate different cases and show the difference.

Comment: @BGM: Your jumping over the critial point: He choose; 1/2 for each door, tree is branching up, therefore the trees as shown, resulting in odds of 1/2 for switchting as well as for staying. Can't be right. Whats wrong with the trees?

Comment: You are branching conditionally in a very strange way. Why do you branch more if you by chance choose the car?

Comment: Also why are people always assuming the person actually wants a car?

Comment: Well thanks for be such a supportive community. After all I was able to figure out, what is wrong with those trees, but since everybody think, that it is already answered somewhere else without presenting how those answers are linked to counting paths in a tree, I am not able to answer my own question.

Comment: Your tree is fine, but you should be weighting the branches by their probabilities.  Contestant picks 1, 2, or 3 should each be given weight 1/3.  In case 1, Monte opens door 2 should be given weight 1; in case 2, Monte opens door 1 should be given weight 1; in case 3, Monte opens door 1 should be given weight 1/2, as should Monte opens door 2.  Now if we look at the switching branches, the contestant will win 1/3*1+1/3*1=2/3 of the time, and will lose 1/3 * 1/2+1/3*1/2 = 1/3 of the time.

Comment: @WillOrrick Thank you very much. That's exactly what's missing there. After reformulate to colored balls and urns, I found out. I would have answered, but.. anyhow.. Thank!